# How can I tell if the text was truncated when I copy a text into an input box with a maxlength attribute

Tags: javascript, html, input, paste, maxlength

HTML input element has a maxlength attribute, which prevents inputting a text longer than the maxlength . Upon pasting a text into the input box, if the text is longer than the maxlength, it will be truncated to the exact length of maxlength. How can I tell if the text was truncated or not please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to know if the length of the value of an input element is the same as the maxlength of that element, you could do something like this (using JQuery).

```
var $el =  $("#myInputElement")
var l = $el.val().length;
var ms = $el.attr("maxlength");
var m = parseInt(ms, 10);

// at this point m and l are maxlength and actual length
```

This however is not the same as a truncated value, it may simply be that exact length.

If you want to know if a user is still writing after reaching the maxlength, you could use look at the keyup event and whether or not the input is focused. However, to compare the clipboard with your input, you might have to resort to Flash.

In short, there is no good solution.

Comment: I am wiling to use JavaScript. However, what I want to know is, when the input length is exactly the maxlength, whether the text was copied form a longer text somewhere else. Probably not comparing the length before sending the form, hopefully I can know it immediately after the text being pasted. Yes, we are sure that if the length is smaller, it must not be truncated. How about when the length is exactly the maxlength?

Comment: @WawaBrother updated answer with your clarification, someone downvoted for me being too slow though!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Well, I was surprised to see such a quick downvote as well. Not me, must be someone else. :)

Comment: @WawaBrother please tell me if you need any clarifications, however I tried that in JSFIddle and it worked fine

Comment: No I don't. However your answer doesn't solve my problem. I am more interested in the case when a text longer than maxlength is being truncated.

Comment: @WawaBrother as I explained earlier, there is no way to actually know if the user intended to input more text. I guess you could get rid of the maxlength attribute, then truncate using javascript instead. That way you would get the whole text, and be able to know when you truncate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18428/discussion-between-wawabrother-and-eakron)